# jQuery-File-Upload - Carrierwave - No progress callbacks

Tags: ruby, jquery-file-upload

Like many others, I've followed Rails-Cast #381, jQuery File Upload, and after struggling, I have most of the pieces working.  I can successfully upload one or more files to Amazon S3 and create the corresponding rows in my database.  I've been stuck for a couple of days now though on getting the progress bars to work.  They appear and sit there while the file does upload and the result appears in my list when it's finished, bu the progress bar stays white. The problem seems to be that I'm not getting the callbacks.  I haven't been able to get anything to work for progress:, progressall:, or :done.

I have a Document model and the upload is straightforward.  I'm using the session id to keep track of the document until my second step in my process, so that is added in the create step.  Here's the relevant code:

Documents Controller:

```
...
def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    @document.session = request.session_options[:id]

respond_to do |format|
    if @document.save
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to documents_path, notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @document }
    else
        format.js
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

documents.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#new_document').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", data.files[0]))
      $('#new_document').append(data.context)
      data.submit()
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
    progressall: (e, data) ->
      overallProgress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      $('#all_progress .bar').css('width', overallProgress + '%')
    done: (e, data) ->
      alert("All finished")
```

index.html.erb

```
(Table of documents here - new uploads insert porperly)

<h2>Upload Document</h2>
<%= form_for Document.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :original, multiple: true, name: "document[original]" %>
  <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
<% end %>
<div id="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>

<div id="all_progress">
  <div class="upload">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div class="upload">
  {%=o.name%}
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```

From the javascript, I should see an alert pop-up at the end of the upload as well, but that never happens. It does show at the beginning of the upload if I put it in the add: section.  That's working but everything else under .fileupload seems to never be called.

Suggestions on where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

Things are working now (as always seems to happen when I post a question).  I should have noticed this when I did the post, but in two places where I thought I had four spaces, I had a tab.  Apparently coffeescript does not interpret tabs as sets of spaces. That didn't throw an error, but it didn't line up  *progress: (e, data) ->*  properly and everything underneath that was ignored.